# Mysql Where clause not fetching data

Tags: mysql

guage_names is varchar
incharge_id is integer
table has a column option_id which is unique,primary and autoincreament.

There is a row in the table with incharge_id 86

But the query is failing.

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'option WHERE incharge_id = 260' at line 1

```
SELECT guage_names FROM option WHERE incharge_id = 86
```

Comment: Delimit your table name

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
SELECT guage_names FROM `option` WHERE incharge_id = 86
```

`option` is a reserved keyword (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html)

Answer (score 1):

OPTION is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).
You need to wrap it in backticks.

```
SELECT guage_names FROM `option` WHERE incharge_id = 86
```

Pay attention to the special backtick.
[From the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html):

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”) If the
>   ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote
>   identifiers within double quotation marks

You should also consider changing the name of the table. It's bad practice to use reserved words for table/column names as it brings additional complexity as you have seen.

Comment: ..................................thanks

Answer (score 1):

As other people already said, it's a reserved word.

Don't **USE** it. You should consider **RENAMING** this table to any other name - since it's not a reserved word, also.

Comment: could not thought that either !! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add backticks for table and column names `guage_names` if they contain empty spaces,but empty spaces in table names are not OK.